# Rails testing: ensure authorization (Pundit) is enforced in all controllers and actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, authorization, pundit

I'm writing RSpec tests for a Rails 4.2 application which uses Pundit for authorization.

I'd like to test whether authorization is enforced in all actions of all controllers, to avoid unintentionally providing public access to sensitive data in case a developer forgets to call `policy_scope` (on `#index` actions) and `authorize` (on all other actions).

One possible solution is to mock these methods in all controller unit tests. Something like `expect(controller).to receive(:authorize).and_return(true)` and `expect(controller).to receive(:policy_scope).and_call_original`. However, that would lead to a lot of code repetition. This line could be placed within a custom matcher or a helper method in `spec/support` but calling it in every spec of every controller also seems repetitive. Any ideas on how to achieve this in a DRY way?

In case you are wondering, Pundit's policy classes are tested separately, as shown in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/164812/unit-testing-authorization-policies-in-rails-with-rspec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like you could use something like this up in spec_helper. Note that I'm assuming a naming convention where you have the word "index" in the index level answers, so that your spec might look like this:

```
describe MyNewFeaturesController, :type => :controller do

  describe "index" do
    # all of the index tests under here have policy_scope applied
  end

  # and these other tests have authorize applied
  describe 'show' do
  end

  describe 'destroy' do
  end
end
```

and here is the overall configuration:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :type => :controller) do |spec|
    # if the spec description has "index" in the name, then use policy-level authorization
    if spec.metadata[:full_description] =~ /\bindex\b/
      expect(controller).to receive(:policy_scope).and_call_original
    else 
      expect(controller).to receive(:authorize).and_call_original
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I forgot to mention that `authorize` should be expected on all actions of all controllers, except for `#index` actions which should call `policy_scope` instead. Sorry... Any other ideas?

Comment: Would you be willing to use a naming convention for your tests? ie, tests that need authorize would have authorize in their path, and tests that require policy_scope would have policy_scope in their path, and tests that don't need either might have 'unauthorized' in their path? if so, I edited the answer to reflect that (it was unreadable as a comment)

Comment: `spec.description` returns the description of the example (`it`), not the `describe` block. Your code works if we replace it with `RSpec.current_example.metadata[:full_description]` or `spec.metadata[:full_description]`. I believe that's a good naming convention (which I already use). The regex flexibility is nice, it works with `describe` blocks with names such as `GET index` and `GET #index`. The only problem is that the expectation is added to all examples. One example per `describe` block (one example per action) would suffice. Anyway, that's the best solution I have so far. Thanks.

Comment: Additonal note: We'd better use `expect(controller).to receive(:policy_scope).and_call_original`. Given that the code goes in `spec_helper.rb` and not on the spec files, other developers (or my future self) may not notice that `policy_scope` was mocked and have a hard time diagnosing why it is returning an unexpected (and invalid) value such as `true`.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer - I can see you are hard at work on it, I was only really kibbitzing and hadn't tested my code. If you want, I'll make those edits.

Comment: So I took your edits. It's probably possible to only check the first example ... let me look. Sorta depends how hacky we want to be - global variables come to mind

Comment: Not sure I'd like to go as far as global variables, but I appreciate your help very much :)

Comment: Have you thought of using shared_examples, like this in the docs? https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples. I'll gin up another answer using that, maybe.

Comment: Yes, I have considered shared examples. They reduce repetition but do not eliminate it. I'm currently working on a solution involving metaprogramming (I'll post it soon), but it's beginning to feel too hacky. Maybe the simplest and most readable way (e.g. shared examples) is best, even if it entails some code repetition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146262/discussion-between-rob-and-brunofacca).

Answer (score 2):

Pundit already provides a mechanism to guarantee a developer can't forget to authorize during the execution of a controller action:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Pundit
  after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
  after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index
end
```

This instructs Pundit to `raise` if the auth wasn't performed. As long as all your controllers are tested, this will cause the spec to fail.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit#ensuring-policies-and-scopes-are-used

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already use these methods provided by Pundit. Although they are very useful, I would prefer our tests do not depend on them. If for some reason they are not called, the test suite will pass even if some controllers do not call `authorize` or `policy_scope`. Or maybe I'm just being paranoid...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using shared_examples, the before :suite hook, and metaprogramming that might get at what you need.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite, :type => :controller) do |spec|
      it_should_behave_like("authorized_controller")
  end
end
```

and over in spec_helper

```
shared_examples_for "authorized_controller" do
  # expects controller to define index_params, create_params, etc
  describe "uses pundit" do 
    HTTP_VERB = {
      :create => :post, :update=>:put, :destroy=>:delete 
    }
    %i{ new create show edit index update destroy}.each do |action|
       if controller.responds_to action
        it "for #{action}" do
          expect(controller).to receive(:policy_scope) if :action == :index
          expect(controller).to receive(:authorize) unless :action == :index
          send (HTTP_VERB[action]||:get), action
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks again. We could probably simplify the `send` line by replacing it with `process(action, HTTP_VERB[action]||:get, send "#{action}_params")`. Also, we could retrieve a list of actions and methods for all controllers by looking at `defaults[:controller]` and `defaults[:action]` within `Rails.application.routes.set`. Unfortunately, implementing `index_params`, `create_params` and so on in the controllers is not viable. Even if it was viable, we would have to provide valid parameters (e.g., use `FactoryGirl.attributes_for`) for the tests to pass.

Comment: You know, maybe you don't care what parameters are passed in - you really only care that the controller checks authorization, which it should do before checking the parameters.

Comment: Another approach is make a spec suite called "verify authorization for all controllers", where you walk through the list of routes defined within Rails.application.routes.set, writing the appropriate test for every action and controller - sort of a hyrid of the two approaches.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I was AFK this weekend. I did write a piece of code that loops through all controllers (descendants of `ApplicationController`) and based on their routes, creates tests for all actions. However, without passing valid parameters to the `get`, `post`, `patch` and `delete` methods, the tests fail as the Active Record methods called in the controller (`find`, `update`, `destroy`) require valid params, at least a valid ID. Can you think of a way to circumvent this so the tests only care whether the `authorize` or `policy_scope` methods are called?

Comment: Maybe put a try-catch in the test and catch the ActiveRecord exceptions gracefully, ignore them, and finish the test?

Comment: That only works when `authorize` or `policy_scope` is called before the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception happens. Will create a new answer with my latest attempt as it is too big for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the code for my latest attempt.

Please note that:

- **You should probably not use this code** as it feels overly complex and hacky.
- It does not work if `authorize` or `policy_scope` is called after an exception happens. Exceptions will occur if a tested action calls Active Record methods such as `find`, `update` and `destroy` without providing them valid parameters. The following code creates fake parameters with empty values. An empty ID is invalid and will result in a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. Will update the code once I find a solution for this.

`spec/controllers/all_controllers_spec.rb`

```
# Test all descendants of this base controller controller
BASE_CONTROLLER = ApplicationController

# To exclude specific actions:
# "TasksController" => [:create, :new, :index]
# "API::V1::PostsController" => [:index]
#
# To exclude entire controllers:
# "TasksController" => nil
# "API::V1::PostsController" => nil
EXCLUDED = {
  'TasksController' => nil
}

def expected_auth_method(action)
  action == 'index' ? :policy_scope : :authorize
end

def create_fake_params(route)
  # Params with non-nil values are required to "No route matches..." error
  route.parts.map { |param| [param, ''] }.to_h
end

def extract_action(route)
  route.defaults[:action]
end

def extract_http_method(route)
  route.constraints[:request_method].to_s.delete("^A-Z")
end

def skip_controller?(controller)
  EXCLUDED.key?(controller.name) && EXCLUDED[controller.name].nil?
end

def skip_action?(controller, action)
  EXCLUDED.key?(controller.name) &&
    EXCLUDED[controller.name].include?(action.to_sym)
end

def testable_controllers
  Rails.application.eager_load!
  BASE_CONTROLLER.descendants.reject {|controller| skip_controller?(controller)}
end

def testable_routes(controller)
  Rails.application.routes.set.select do |route|
    route.defaults[:controller] == controller.controller_path &&
      !skip_action?(controller, extract_action(route))
  end
end

# Do NOT name the loop variable "controller" or it will override the
# "controller" object available within RSpec controller specs.
testable_controllers.each do |tested_controller|
  RSpec.describe tested_controller, :focus, type: :controller do
    # login_user is implemented in spec/support/controller_macros.rb
    login_user
    testable_routes(tested_controller).each do |route|
      action = extract_action(route)
      http_method = extract_http_method(route)

      describe "#{http_method} ##{action}" do
        it 'enforces authorization' do
          expect(controller).to receive(expected_auth_method(action)).and_return(true)
          begin
            process(action, http_method, create_fake_params(route))
          rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: seems pretty reasonable. It handles most of the cases, and you can always hand code the exception cases.

Comment: @Rob: Without passing valid parameters (especially a valid ID) to `process`, when Active Record methods such as `find`, `update` and `destroy` are called, an  `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception is thrown. Even if we rescue the exception, the code only works when `authorize` or `policy_scope` is called **before** the Active Record method. However, `authorize` takes a model instance as an argument, so most actions call `find` before calling `authorize`. Hence, the above code fails in the majority of cases. Any ideas on how to circumvent this? Thanks again.

Comment: Yah, so it's only really important to stub out the find. But I can't think of a generic way to do it, since we don't know the class for the controller (or even if there is one). If you knew the class (say Foo), you could do this: "allow(Foo).to receive(:find).and_return(Foo.new)". But this is fragile in so many ways.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I've had the same idea and ran into the same problem. Given that we are unable to know which model or models will be used by each action, we would have to stub `find` (and possibly other Active Record methods) for all models, which IMO would be waaaaaay too hacky. Looks like we're out of options and, aside from writing all the tests manually, your first answer seems to be the best choice.

Comment: I think you are right. It's too bad, i really liked your approach of generating all the tests by walking the routes, that was clever.